# Check user settings before sending an email notification in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, notifications

I have a `receiveEmail` boolean field in the User model of a Laravel application. How do I ensure that mail notifications respect this field, and only sends the email to the user if the field is true?

What I want is that this code:

```
$event = new SomeEvent($somedata);
Auth::user()->notify($event);
```

where SomeEvent is a class that extends Notification and implements 'mail' on the `via()` method, only sends an email if the user has allowed emails.

Comment: Depends on your email logic. Are you sending an email directly to an email, or are you querying for a user matching that email first? You need to provide some code here; we won't be able to help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a new Channel that implements the checking. In app/channels, add your channel, something like this:

```php
namespace App\Channels;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class UserCheckMailChannel extends MailChannel
{
    /**
     * Send the given notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @param  \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification  $notification
     * @return void
     */
    public function send($notifiable, Notification $notification)
    {
        // check if user should receive emails. Do whatever check you need here.
        if ($notifiable instanceof User && !$notifiable->receiveEmails) {
            return;
        }
        // yes, convert to mail and send it
        $message = $notification->toMail($notifiable);
        if (!$message) {
            return;
        }

        parent::send($notifiable, $notification);
    }
}
```

Then bind your class on `Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` to the old mail class:

```
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()

        $this->app->bind(
            \Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel::class,
            UserCheckMailChannel::class
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Have any one checked this via() method:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/notifications#specifying-delivery-channels

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
        // $notifiable object is User instance for most cases
        $wantsEmail = $notifiable->settings['wants_email']; // your own logic
        if(!$wantsEmail){
            // no email only database log
            return ['database'];
        }
        return ['database', 'mail'];
}
```

I hope this will work while sending notifications to multiple users too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to create new method in user model like this..

user model file..

```
public function scopeNotifyMail() {
        if($this->receiveEmail == true) { //if field is enable email other wise not send..
            $event = new SomeEvent($somedata);
            $this->notify($event);
        }    
}
```

and now call like this in controller..

```
Auth::user()->notifyMail();
```

or

```
App\User::find(1)->notifyMail();
```

or

```
App\User::where('id',1)->first()->notifyMail();
```

Comment: I have several events, not a single one. It would add a ton of methods to the user model, and it wouldn't handle user collections in something like `Notification::send($users, $event)`;